# Python - Why is the default value for next initialized if it doesn't get used?

Tags: python, iterator, initialization

Like the title says, I'm wondering why the default value in a next expression is initialized regardless of it being used. An example of this is below.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Test object created")
print(next((i for i in range(1)), Test()))
```

Previously I would have thought this to only print out `0` and not `Test object created` as well as `0`. I recently found out this wasn't the case through a bug caused by this behavior.

Is there some reason for this? Was this a design decision?

Comment: "I recently found out this wasn't the case through a bug caused by this behavior" - What is the issue here, you are passing the two functions as arguments to `print` function and it is processing those as expected.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha Presumably the creation of the sentinel object has some side effect that wreaks havoc if it's executed when it shouldn't be executed. That is some very questionable design, of course, but it's conceivable.

Comment: What is here that is being executed which shouldn't be executed?

Comment: @delnan That's correct. It wasn't my design, but the object would hit an api on creation.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha OP expects that `Test()` is not executed. Note: that's an argument to `next`, not to `print`!

Comment: Yeah @delnan, indeed! And any argument being passed 'has' to be evaluated first, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design decision here is that `next` is just an ordinary function, not special language syntax. And in any function call, all arguments are evaluated before the function starts executing. `next` is nothing special, it just follows the same rules as everyone else.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm not sure why I thought it would be otherwise. I guess I wasn't really thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments are always evaluated before the function is called, regardless of whether the function ends up needing them. You could design a language that doesn't work that way, but it has far-reaching effects throughout the language design and how functions are used, since you have to worry about the argument expression evaluating to something different if the variables it depends on change before it's evaluated.